# List elements appearing in inspector but not in script references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list, list_of_targetable, into which I spawn enemy instances. I can see during play in the inspector that the instances are spawning correctly and being put in the list correctly.

When I try to reference those instances, from within the same script, they seemly do not exist, and the `list.Count` returns `0`. Furthermore, the way I am calling `TargetEnemySlot1` is via button, so long after `Start`, when the enemies are initialized.

What gives?

```
public class Targeting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Combatant> current_targets;
    public List<Combatant> list_of_targetable;

    public void TargetEnemySlot1()
    {
        Debug.Log(list_of_targetable.Count);
        current_targets.Add(list_of_targetable[0]);
        current_targets[0].is_target = true;
        current_targets[0].targeting_panel.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Things that interact directly with the lists:

```
public class AbAttack : MonoBehaviour, IAbility
{
public Targeting targeting_for_attack;

public int block_attack_damage = 10;
public int block_attack_repeats = 2;

public bool needs_targets = true;
public bool targets_allies = false;
public bool targets_enemies = true;
public int number_of_targets = 1;


public void Use()
{
    if (needs_targets == true)
    {
        if (targets_enemies == true)
        {
            foreach (Combatant enemy in targeting_for_attack.list_of_targetable)
            {
                enemy.targeting_panel.SetActive(true);

            }
        }
    }
}

public void Enact()
{
    foreach (Combatant enemy in targeting_for_attack.current_targets)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < block_attack_repeats; i++)
        {
            enemy.health = enemy.health - block_attack_damage;
        }

    }
}
}

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Combatant> CombatantList = new List<Combatant>();
public List<Combatant> CombatantInWaitingList = new List<Combatant>();
public List<Combatant> CombatantInCombatList = new List<Combatant>();

Inventory inventory;

public List <GameObject> targeting_panel;
public Targeting targeting_panel_targeting;
public Sprite icon1;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    inventory = Inventory.instance;

    DrainList();
    SpawnList();

}

public void DrainList()
{
    List<Combatant> ToRemoveList = new List<Combatant>();

    foreach (Combatant item in CombatantInWaitingList)
    {
        if (CombatantInCombatList.Count <= 3)
        {
            CombatantInCombatList.Add(item);
            ToRemoveList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    foreach (Combatant item in ToRemoveList)
    {
        CombatantInWaitingList.Remove(item);
    }
}

public void SpawnList()
{
    List<Combatant> ToRemoveList = new List <Combatant>();

    foreach (Combatant item in CombatantInCombatList)
    {
        if (Inventory.instance.items1.Count == 0)
        {
            Combatant data1 = Combatant.CreateInstance("spider", icon1, targeting_panel[0]);
            Inventory.instance.items1.Add(data1);
            targeting_panel_targeting.list_of_targetable.Add(data1);
            ToRemoveList.Add(item);
        }

        if (Inventory.instance.items1.Count == 1)
        {
            Combatant data1 = Combatant.CreateInstance("spider", icon1, targeting_panel[1]);
            Inventory.instance.items1.Add(data1);
            targeting_panel_targeting.list_of_targetable.Add(data1);
            ToRemoveList.Add(item);
        }

        if (Inventory.instance.items1.Count == 2)
        {
            Combatant data1 = Combatant.CreateInstance("spider", icon1, targeting_panel[2]);
            Inventory.instance.items1.Add(data1);
            targeting_panel_targeting.list_of_targetable.Add(data1);
            ToRemoveList.Add(item);
        }

    }

    foreach (Combatant item in ToRemoveList)
    {
        // Add new combataant at that list location FIRST
        CombatantInCombatList.Remove(item);
    }
}
}
```

The IN GAME inspector with the instances spawned correctly:
http://prntscr.com/o629xb

Comment: Could you add the code for `Start` and anything else interacting with those lists?

Comment: I've added the code, one thing that occurs to me is am I somehow creating two instances of the list somewhere in the above code? Maybe that would explain it?